# Hide element with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

This is my HTML:

```
<div id="address"><a id="prev">Prev </a>
<span id="address" class="active">0 Elgin Street</span>
<span id="address" class="passive">1 Elgin Street</span>
<span id="address" class="passive">2 Elgin Street</span>
<span id="address" class="passive">3 Elgin Street</span>
<span id="address" class="passive">4 Elgin Street</span>
<span id="address" class="passive">5 Elgin Street</span>
<span id="address" class="passive">6 Elgin Street</span>
<span id="address" class="passive">7 Elgin Street</span>
<span id="address" class="passive">8 Elgin Street</span>
<span id="address" class="passive">9 Elgin Street</span>
<a id="next"> Next</a></div>
```

I have active and passive classes as you see. When I click next, I want to hide the active button which is the first one this case and then show the next one.

How can I do that with jQuery?

This is the code to get the current element:

```
var current = $('.active', this);
```

However, `current.hide()` does not work why?

Comment: And what is `this` in your context?

Comment: IDs **must** be unique, that's for sure.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I make this for only one element?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26286623/how-can-i-make-this-for-only-one-element)

Comment: @MelanciaUK Not a duplicate.  That looks like a follow up question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the correct way to get the current :

```
var current = $(".active");

$(current).next().attr("class", "active");
$(current).attr("class", "passive");
```

if you want to hide :

```
$(".active").hide();
```

**Edit :**

add it in the click of the link :

```
$("#next").click(function(event) {
    event.stopPropagation();
    var current = $(".active");

    $(current).next().attr("class", "active");
    $(current).attr("class", "passive"); 

});
```

**Edit :**

```
$("#next").click(function(event) {
    event.stopPropagation();
    var current = $(".active");

    $(current).next().addClass("active");
    $(current).next().removeClass("passive");

    $(current).addClass("passive");
    $(current).removeClass("active");

});
```

Comment: thanks. this works for all the spans in the page. I think I should put this. but where?

Comment: add a click event to you link

Comment: can i do that without click event? can i select item with this?

Comment: Why are you setting class with `attr()`? You are blowing away any other classes they may be there. Yes it works in the simple example, but it could lead to issues.

Comment: `current` is already a jQuery object so why wrap it in a `$(current)`?

Answer (score 1):

So use next() to get the next item.

```
$(".active").removeClass("active").next("span.passive").addClass("active").removeClass("passive")
```

with toggleClass

```
$(".active").toggleClass("active passive").next("span.passive").toggleClass("active passive")
```

What this fails to do is handle the situation when you are at the end of the list.

---

```
var current = $('.active', this);
```

Does not work because `this` is probably the anchor you are clicking and the anchor does not have children which the context (aka this) is using.

---

Below is an example showing how to handle when you get to the last item:

```js
$("#address").on("click", "a", function () {  //add click handler to the anchors
  var last = $(".active").toggleClass("active passive");  //Select current active item. It removes active, adds passive classes
  var dir = $(this).data("dir");  //stored the next/prev as a data attribute so one click handler is needed
  var sib = last[dir](".passive");  //Find the next/previous passive sibling
  if (sib.length === 0) {
  sib = last;  //if we can not find the next/previous than just pick the last selected 
  }
  sib.toggleClass("active passive");  //add active and remove passive

});
```

```css
.active {
  display: block
}
.passive {
  display: none
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="address"> <a id="prev" data-dir="prev">Prev </a>
  <span class="active">0 Elgin Street</span>
  <span class="passive">1 Elgin Street</span>
  <span class="passive">2 Elgin Street</span>
  <span class="passive">3 Elgin Street</span>
  <span class="passive">4 Elgin Street</span>
  <span class="passive">5 Elgin Street</span>
  <span class="passive">6 Elgin Street</span>
  <span class="passive">7 Elgin Street</span>
  <span class="passive">8 Elgin Street</span>
  <span class="passive">9 Elgin Street</span>
  <a id="next" data-dir="next"> Next</a>
</div>
```

Comment: it would be better if you use `next('.passive')` for the sake of the last `span`

Comment: Was just updating that. :)

Comment: The question asks why`current.hide()` does not work.

Comment: actually i want to create two variables current and next. When you click next, current supposed to be hidden(passive) and next should be active.