# How can I make this for only one element?

Tags: javascript, jquery

This code works for all the spans in the page. Where should I put `this` for the specific one?

```js
    var next = function(e) {
      var current = $('.active');
      var prev = $('#prev');
      pos = $('.active').attr('id');

      $("#num").text('(' + pos + '/' + researchPlaces.length + ')');


      $(current).next().attr("class", "active");
      $(current).attr("class", "passive");
      e.stopPropagation();

    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="address"><a id="prev">Prev </a>
  <span id="address" class="active">0 Elgin Street</span>
  <span id="address" class="passive">1 Elgin Street</span>
  <span id="address" class="passive">2 Elgin Street</span>
  <span id="address" class="passive">3 Elgin Street</span>
  <span id="address" class="passive">4 Elgin Street</span>
  <span id="address" class="passive">5 Elgin Street</span>
  <span id="address" class="passive">6 Elgin Street</span>
  <span id="address" class="passive">7 Elgin Street</span>
  <span id="address" class="passive">8 Elgin Street</span>
  <span id="address" class="passive">9 Elgin Street</span>
  <a id="next"> Next</a>
</div>
```

Comment: IDs **must** be unique.

Comment: You should make all of your `ids` unique. E.g., `address1`, `address2`, etc.

Comment: It's unbelievable the number of people that wouldn't mind having someone else sharing their `id`. How nice would be that?

Comment: I made them like 1,2,3,4,5 but still does not work.

Comment: I see you did not use my code from your other question. What are you expecting pos to be? What is `$("#num")` ? What is `researchPlaces`?

Comment: Why would you place your elements in a div labeled `id="address"` and then have spans inside of it with the same exact id. Even if id's didn't need to be unique your code is still an eyesore. You should have a parent class and then child classes with unique ids. Such as Matt Cremeens has stated as well as others.

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="container">
  <span id="address1" class="passive active">0 Elgin Street</span>
  <span id="address2" class="passive">1 Elgin Street</span>
  <span id="address3" class="passive">2 Elgin Street</span>
  <span id="address4" class="passive">3 Elgin Street</span>
  <span id="address5" class="passive">4 Elgin Street</span>
  <span id="address6" class="passive">5 Elgin Street</span>
  <span id="address7" class="passive">6 Elgin Street</span>
  <span id="address8" class="passive">7 Elgin Street</span>
  <span id="address9" class="passive">8 Elgin Street</span>
  <span id="address10" class="passive">9 Elgin Street</span>
</div>
```

Now your JS example

```
$(function(){
    var current = $('.active');
    var prev = $('#prev');
    $('.active').on('click',function(){
         alert(this.id);
     });
 });
```

So if active changes then you can use `this` in the click event. Hopefully the HTML and JS will help you to clarify where you went wrong. Once you state what `pos` and `researchPlace` should be then I'll update it for you.

Answer (score 0):

So let me work off my last answer that I helped you with.

```js
var addyCount = $(".addy").length;  // get the count of items

$("#address").on("click", "a", function () {  //add click handler to the anchors
  var last = $(".active").toggleClass("active passive");  //Select current active item. It removes active, adds passive classes
  var dir = $(this).data("dir");  //stored the next/prev as a data attribute so one click handler is needed
  var sib = last[dir](".passive");  //Find the next/previous passive sibling
  if (sib.length === 0) {
      sib = last;  //if we can not find the next/previous than just pick the last selected 
  }
  sib.toggleClass("active passive");  //add active and remove passive

  $("#num").html((sib.index(".addy") + 1) + "/" + addyCount);  //index() starts at zero, so need to add one. 

});
```

```css
.active {
  display: block
}
.passive {
  display: none
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="num">1</div>
<div id="address"> <a id="prev" data-dir="prev">Prev </a>
  <span class="addy active">0 Elgin Street</span>
  <span class="addy passive">1 Elgin Street</span>
  <span class="addy passive">2 Elgin Street</span>
  <span class="addy passive">3 Elgin Street</span>
  <span class="addy passive">4 Elgin Street</span>
  <span class="addy passive">5 Elgin Street</span>
  <span class="addy passive">6 Elgin Street</span>
  <span class="addy passive">7 Elgin Street</span>
  <span class="addy passive">8 Elgin Street</span>
  <span class="addy passive">9 Elgin Street</span>
  <a id="next" data-dir="next"> Next</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

test this ;) :

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>this is a test</title>
    <meta content="">
      <style></style>
      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
    var prev = $("#prev");
    var next = $("#next");
    var cur = $("#address .active"); /* just spans that in the #address ! */
    var curNum = parseInt(cur.text().match(/\d+/));
    /* ############ the next function  #############*/
    next.click(function(){
    if(cur.next().attr("id") != "next"){
    curNum += 1;
    $("#num").text(curNum);
    cur.attr("class","addy passive");
    cur = cur.next();
    cur.attr("class","addy active");
    }
    });
    /* ########### the prev function ###############*/
    prev.click(function(){
    if(cur.prev().attr("id") != "prev"){
    curNum -= 1;
    $("#num").text(curNum);
    cur.attr("class","addy passive");
    cur = cur.prev();
    cur.attr("class","addy active");
    }
    });
    });
      </script>
    </head>
    <body>

      <div id="num">1</div>
      <div id="address"> <a id="prev" data-dir="prev">Prev </a>
      <span class="addy active">0 Elgin Street</span>
      <span class="addy passive">1 Elgin Street</span>
      <span class="addy passive">2 Elgin Street</span>
      <span class="addy passive">3 Elgin Street</span>
      <span class="addy passive">4 Elgin Street</span>
      <span class="addy passive">5 Elgin Street</span>
      <span class="addy passive">6 Elgin Street</span>
      <span class="addy passive">7 Elgin Street</span>
      <span class="addy passive">8 Elgin Street</span>
      <span class="addy passive">9 Elgin Street</span>
      <a id="next" data-dir="next"> Next</a>
      </div>

    </body>
  </html>
```